# Import-Certificate with a variable

Tags: powershell, certificate, x509certificate, windows-server

I have a script, where in the beginning I store certificates to a variable, like this:

`$ToRemove = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My | ? (conditions)`

`$CertsInStore = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My`

Then I have foreach loop to delete the selected certificates. Later in the script I test certain situation and if an error occurs, I want to return the removed certificates back. Will this work?

`Import-Certificate $ToRemove -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My`

Or do I have to do it in a different way? How, if so?

Comment: You should check all conditions before removing anything. It is much better than reimporting removed certificates.

Comment: That's unfortunately not possible. I need to remove all certificates with DNS name as subject, with purpose Client authentication, Server authentication, then import a new one with these parameters and in case that fails for some reason, return back the original state. Also I need to ensure, that there are no certificates with DNS name as subject, with other purposes. So first I delete the certificates fulfilling the subject and purpose conditions and then check, if there are some other certificates with the subject. If there are, I need to import back the deleted certs and exit the script.

Comment: It is just about the algorithm. You can import new certificate first and then perform store cleanup from unnecessary certificates excluding newly installed certificate.

Comment: And how do I do that? How do I identify the newly imported certificate and exclude it from deletion?